# Connecting external display at 60 hz on a MacBook 12" 2016

Tags: macbook-pro, display, resolution, displayport

Has anyone got MacBook 12 inch (2016) working with an external display at 60 hz. I know 4K runs at 30 hz unless you do the hack to MacOS but I was wondering how 1920x1080 or 2560x1440 performed.

Comment: Theoretically both of those resolutions should work at 60Hz. It depends what versions of the adapters and cords you use, of course